# Gap on left when button set to null for radio button in Android

Tags: android, layout, text, radio-button, radio-group

I am working on an Android app where I have a radiogroup with 3 radio button.

The following is the code for the same:

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radioButtonGroup" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/oneRadioButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:button = "@null"
  android:text="@string/one_text"
  android:gravity="center" >
  </RadioButton>
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/twoRadioButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/two_text"
  android:button = "@null"  android:gravity="center">
  </RadioButton>
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/threeRadioButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/three_text"
   android:button = "@null"  android:gravity="center" >
  </RadioButton>
 </RadioGroup>
```

From the code you can see that I have set android:button = "@null". I have done this just because I don't want the button and I just want the text.

My problem is that even when I have set button to null I am able to see a gap on left side text for each radio button, like this

```
|         (gap)rbt1(gap)rbt2(gap)rbt3     |
|                                         |
```

How do I remove this gap? I tried `android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"` which made the text closer but this also made the button overlap each other.

Comment: How does it layout if you use an actual 0-size drawable, such as `android.R.color.transparent`?

Comment: I am trying this android:button = "@drawable/android.R.color.transparent" but this is giving me and compilation error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` for radiobutton in xml file like this with `android:button = "@null"` also

Comment: do you want me to use this with android:button="@null"

Comment: This worked... I used android:background="@android:color/transparent" along with android:button = "@null" and that made the magic... thank you... I would like to accept your answer so can you modify it by adding to use is with android:button = "@null"